# How do I run tests in Scala.js using a vite configuration?

Tags: vite, scala.js

The (relatively) new Scala.js vite plugin has made Scala frontend development so much easier than the sbt webpack bundler plugin I had been using previously. Unfortunately, however, I have not been able to figure out a way to make my JS library dependencies (via NPM) available to tests. With scalajs-bundler I was able to manage my npm dependencies within `build.sbt` using the `npmDependency` and `npmDevDependency` settings. I was eventually able to get sbt to bundle these dependencies into tests.

Is there a way to do this with vite? What is the best way to bundle my npm dependencies defined in `package.json` into my tests?